# Is there any working example of Google Buzz API (Labs) for Android?

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-buzz

The new set of Google APIs could be used in Android with the Client Library and can be authenticated using

1. OAuth1.0
2. OAuth2.0
3. Client Authentication (android).

Can someone show me an example of Client Authentication using `GoogleAccountManager` class?
I can't get one working.

Also when I use OAuth2.0 and use a redirect URL like `buzz-sample:///` and add an intent filter to the Manifest like

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="buzz-sample" />
</intent-filter>
```

> It throws an error in the browser
>   invalid-request: Invalid parameter
>   value for redirect_uri: Missing
>   authority: buzz-sample:///
>
> Error 400

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty good example here that should do what you want. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/buzz-v1-json-oauth2-android-sample/?repo=samples

Here's a small code snippet demonstrates how to use AccountManager#getAuthToken to get an AccessToken: http://chiarg.com/?p=429

Comment: Great example! Worked like butter. I had worked this out but not this simple a solution. Had to include around 20 libraries from Google-Client-APIs to get that working.